# vector with reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, vector, reinterpret-cast

The following code inserts only one value to the vector `col`.
The code is extracted from DBMS code base (for importing files), specifically, it is from [1](https://github.com/TimoKersten/db-engine-paradigms/blob/ae3286b279ad26ab294224d630d650bc2f2f3519/src/common/runtime/Import.cpp#L134)

The code uses void* to be able to read any field type (int, float, and so on).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void add(std::vector<void*> &col){
  reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>&>(col).push_back( 1);
  reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>&>(col).push_back( 2);
  reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>&>(col).push_back( 13);
}
int main() {
 std::vector<void*> col;

 add(col);
 cout << col.size() << endl;
 for(int i=0;i<col.size();i++)
    cout <<reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>&> (col)[i] <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure how this code work?

Comment: I find it interesting that this code inserts anything into the vector at all.

Comment: Why are you using a `void*` for the type in the vector?

Comment: int and pointers often have different sizes which will break this. Otherwise you still are looking at UB galore too.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is a *huge* "there's probably a bug here" flag. Also; *Why* `void*`?

Comment: `void *` should only be used in C++ when interfacing with an API that demands it and a few extremely rare edge cases.  Instead of `void *`, use templates, overloads, inheritance, and `std::variant` if it's supported.

Comment: And before you run into next trouble: `col.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<intptr_t>(value)));` – you need the intermediate step (intptr_t) to get an integer of appropriate size to be reinterpret-casted! Still I agree with the `most likely bug' fraction...

Comment: If you would explain why you feel you need to do this, I'm confident we can point you to a better, safer and easier solution.

Comment: Oh my. If the source contains *such* code – and if I additionally see limiting string lengths not simply to a maximum, but only to a subset of these limited lengths (`RTType` enum!), I'd immediately exclude it from use in my own projects...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is exhibiting **undefined behavior**.

`std::vector<void*>` and `std::vector<int>` are two completely separate and unrelated types, you can't safely cast between them the way you are, especially since there is no guarantee that `void*` and `int` are the same byte size.

Cast the *values* you are pushing, don't cast the `vector` itself, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

void add(std::vector<void*> &col) {
    col.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<intptr_t>(1)));
    col.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<intptr_t>(2)));
    col.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<intptr_t>(13)));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<void*> col;

    add(col);

    cout << col.size() << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<col.size();i++)
        cout << reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(col[i]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you really should be using the proper container type to begin with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void add(std::vector<int> &col) {
    col.push_back(1);
    col.push_back(2);
    col.push_back(13);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> col;

    add(col);

    cout << col.size() << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<col.size();i++)
        cout << col[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is unfortunately not my code. it is extracted from https://github.com/TimoKersten/db-engine-paradigms/blob/ae3286b279ad26ab294224d630d650bc2f2f3519/src/common/runtime/Import.cpp#L134

Comment: @Khalefa then you can't trust using that code. What it is doing is not safe.

Comment: @SRG I'm well aware of what `(u)intptr_t` is and how to work with it, thank you very much. I stand by my answer.